# Trimming column data in Snowflake

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Teradata to Trim Leading or Trailing Zero "0" OR any Character we can use

```
TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM COLUMN) OR TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM COLUMN)
```

In Snowflake it seems this doesn't work! Do we know the alternative in Snowflake for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ltrim`. This function removes leading characters, including whitespace, from a string, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ltrim.html#examples)

```
select ltrim('#000000123', '0');
```

Gives:

```
+---------------------------+
| LTRIM('000000123', '0') |
|---------------------------|
| 123                       |
+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

- Scenario 1

  If there is blank space on either side of text of oracle.

  Solution

  ```
  select trim(column_name) from table_name
  ```
- Scenario 2

  If we have zero and special character.

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(Column_name,'[#$@!~*)({}.,:;"0]') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 3

  If we have number and special character.

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(Column_name,'[#$@!~*)({}.,:;"0123456789]') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 4

  If we have zero,blank space before/after text and special character .

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(Column_name),'[#$@!~*)({}.,:;"0]') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 5

  If we have number,blank space before/after text and special character .

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(Column_name),'[#$@!~*)({}.,:;"0123456789]') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 6

  If we have blank space in between the text.

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Column_name,' ') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 7

  If we have blank space in before ,after and between the text.

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(Column_name),' ') FROM table_name;
  ```
- Scenario 8

  If we have blank space between the text with special character.

  Solution

  ```
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(column_name),' '),'[#$@!~*{}.,:-_;"]') FROM table_name;
  ```

Similarly other combination of sql statement can be create.